How to create HTTP signature for Cybersource with Netsuite
I am trying to create the http signature to access cybersource refunds API using Suitescript 2.0. Also, I am using crypto module to create the hash. But I am getting "Authentication Failed" and I have no clue why I am getting this error. Is there any code related to Netsuite for creating the http signature. Thanks in advance.

There are examples for creating various types of hashes in the NS help system. Please post enough of your code so we can see where there might be issues with your API use.
